# Whining noise in my front left speaker

Tags: noise, speakers, entertainment-system

There is a whining sound coming from my front-left speaker. It gets louder when I rev the engine. I have a Kicker amp and Sub. Add some pics if possible.My car is Honda city 1.5exi 2001 model

How do I avoid this whine?

Comment: What year, make, model, and trim is your car?

Comment: @ZachMierzejewski updated the question

Comment: sounds like interference from the alternator or ignition. is there a capacitor on your ignition system?

Comment: @Ben Don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check all your vehicles ground points,  including engine/alternator, stereo head, amp antenna etc for bad grounds.

Here's a link that will help...

http://www.crutchfield.com/S-o2oP9lxwr8F/learn/learningcenter/car/noise_suppressors_installation_guide.html